# Docker Compose networking: Bridge driver with access to host machine

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

Is there any way to have a microservices architecture in Docker, using Docker Compose, in such a way that the communication between containers is with the default `bridge` value driver (*i.e.* I didn't specify any `network_mode` in any service in `docker-compose.yml`), but all the containers having access to a common service in the host machine?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's the way it works out of the box – don't manually specify any networking settings in `docker-compose.yml` and this should just work.  You'll need to know some IP address or DNS name for the host.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for your comment. Yes, I didn't specify any `network_mode` in any service, but I would like to connect from my containers to a service in the host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your containers always have access to your host machine.

Under Linux, you can just use the address of the default gateway inside the container; this will be the address of the bridge on your host to which your container is attached.  Any host services that are listening on all interfaces will be available at this address. Assuming your container has the `iproute` package installed, you could get the gateway address using something like:

```
ip route | awk '$1 == "default" {print $3}'
```

You could of course use the address of any host interface and pass that it as an environment variable (`docker run -e HOSTADDR=192.168.23.5 ...`); using the gateway address is convenient because it is discoverable from inside the container.

Under Docker for MacOS or Docker for Windows, you can use the special hostname `host.docker.internal` to refer to the host, as documented for example [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/).

Note that if your host service is not listening on all interfaces or if you have a restrictive firewall configuration, you may need to make changes before the above will work.

Comment: Bummer that `host.docker.internal` doesn't work on Linux, any idea why? Seems like something worth adding to Docker's DNS service.

Comment: I imagine because (a) a container isn't meant to interact with the host in a production environment, and (b) on Linux it's trivial to access the host, while under MacOS and Windows, because Docker is running in a VM, it's largely impossible without this special hostname.

Comment: There is a very long thread on GitHub about this issue @Max♦. See https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264#issuecomment-429588648